# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in jmeter for the methods inside the jar file

Tags: jmeter

I have a jar file where i have one java class.I add that to jmeter and call that jar in sampler.When the request is hit I face java.lang.NoSuchMethodError for one of the methods inside that java class.That method doesn't need any maven dependencies as I use default java functions inside it.I tried manually including that jar to jmeter lib folder but no luck.

Comment: show your class, method and your call

Answer (score 0):

Which "sampler" and how do you "call" it?

- Either there is a typo in your code i.e. you're trying to call the function which doesn't exist
- Or there is a typo in your code in terms of passing parameters to the function, in case if it's [overloaded](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_methods_overloading.asp) the candidate is determined in the runtime depending on the argument types, like function expects an integer and you're passing a string to it or something like this

In JMeter you can use Java code in 3 ways:

- in [Java Request sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request)
- in [JUnit Request sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request)
- [write your own plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-develop-a-jmeter-plugin-intro-and-best-practices)

Comment: From my Java Maven framework,I have a baseclass where i have all my reusable functions.I convert this class into a jar file and load it in jmeter. I also convert my whole java project into a runnable jar file and laod in jmeter.Now in one of my sampler,I have my JSR233 Postprocessor.i write groovy script and call the method inside that jar where my whole java project is bundled.So when i run that sampler my http request is hit and after that my jar will execute..

Comment: Now everything looks good.But when the code reaches the line where i call my reusable function from my baseclass,i get Nosuchmethod error. The java  jar file is running properly in CMD and jenkins and also my java code is properly running in eclipse